# standard deviation of the model R2 in LOOCV in caret

Tags: cross-validation, r-squared, caret

I am performing a LOOCV linear model and I got the parameters R2 and RMSE, but I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the standard deviation of the model R2. I tried to do it in the same way I do it for k-fold cross-validation but it does not work.

This is my model

```
train.control <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV")
model_amb <- train(rate ~ volume, data = data_amb, method = "lm", trControl = train.control)
summary(model_amb)
sd(model_amb$resample$Rsquared)
```

This is what I get when I run the last line

```
sd(model_amb$resample$Rsquared)
[1] NA
```

Comment: Do you mean the standard error? The terms are not synonyms.

Comment: It is the standard deviation, I usually calculate the standard deviation around the R-squared value by examining the R-squared from each fold when I do k-fold cross validation. But I think I can not do it if I am doing LOOCV, I would like to know if I can calculate that with LOOCV and if yes, how?

Comment: What happens when you try to calculate the LOOCV standard deviation the same way you calculate it for k-fold?

Comment: I got NA, the code and output is above

Comment: How are you calculating model_amb\$resampleRsquared? Does that have NA values? All NA values?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your question

Comment: How are you calculating your metric on the holdout points?